# How does AC coil relay works?

Tags: ac, relay

If relay coil is specified for AC power we have to take into account thar the magnetic force applied to the moving contact will drop to zero each 10 milliseconds (or 8.3 in case of 60 Hz supply) and stays low for several milliseconds.

So the question is: what forces contacts to stay in 'closed' state during this time?